# Meaning of 'sparse' vs 'dense' data / matrices

Tags: python, dataset, scikit-learn, terminology

In the context of the Scikit-learn library documentation, what do the terms "sparse data" and "dense data" mean? For instance, taken from the entry on [feature selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html):

> If you use sparse data (i.e. data represented as sparse matrices),
>   chi2, mutual_info_regression, mutual_info_classif will deal with the
>   data without making it dense.

Answer (score 10):

A sparse matrix is a matrix with most of its entries being zero. As a consequence of their nature, they can be efficiently represented and stored by only storing the non-zero values and their position within the matrix. Moreover, operations like matrix multiplication can be implemented more efficiently for sparse matrices.

Most of the algorithms implemented in scikit-learn support taking a sparse matrix as the input (particularly, through Scipy's [sparse matrix format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)). However, some of them internally cast input sparse matrices to a conventional dense matrix representation, losing the efficiency of sparse matrices.

The fragment of the documentation you cited just indicates that those particular methods are able to process Scipy's sparse matrices without casting them to dense numpy arrays internally.